# dhcpcd on debian wheezy doesn't seem to be considering /etc/resolv.conf{head|tail}

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2, dhcp, debian-wheezy

I have set up an amazon EC2 instance (with a debian wheezy AMI) having minimal stuff on it, and dhcpcd is present by default.

dhcpcd doesn't seem to be considering /etc/resolv.conf.head or /etc/resolv.conf.tail at all and keeps overwriting my /etc/resolv.conf and thus am unable to add nameservers of my choice.

How can I get entries for my nameservers to stay in /etc/resolv.conf ?

Answer (score 3):

According to `man dhcpcd.conf`, a line with

```
nohook resolv.conf
```

in `dhcpcd.conf` should stop dhcpcd from running the `resolv.conf` hook-script and thus leave your `resolv.conf` untouched. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.

Therefore, I'm using

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

as a workaround.

You could probably also remove the hook-script in `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks`.

Comment: The filename after `nohook` should match the file under `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks`. In my case, that was `20-resolv.conf`. Once I updated the line to `no hook 20-resolv.conf` in `dhcpcd.conf`, it worked without making the file immutable with `chattr`

Answer (score 2):

You can add the namerservers to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address ...
    netmask ...
    gateway ...
    dns-nameservers w.x.y.z w.x.y.z
```

Comment: I do not want to make it a static one; I just wanted dhcpcd to not overwrite /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: The question is about how to make resolv.conf{head|tail} works, not about adding dns servers.